# php error Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all()

Tags: php, mysqli

Shared hosting changes the server in which php website is hosted then when opening the site i have encountered error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all()` i have seen stackoverflow solutions but not clear for me. On my php section mysqli is installed and active thanks.
here is my php file

```
<?php
include 'connection/conn.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mydoc";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$files = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
```

Comment: On the [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-all-mysqlnd) "Available only with mysqlnd."

Comment: What PHP version are you running on? Can you add your php config?

Comment: Code Sprit  my php version is 7.3